# Convert encoded string containg \x characters to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, utf-8, ascii-8bit

I am trying to convert to JSON, a string that contains backslash x encoded character

```
data = "{\"schema\":\"iglu\", \"data\": \"hellox\E2\x80\x99s\"}"
data.to_json
```

However I get the following error:
JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8
from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5@tagtrue/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:34:in `to_json'
Caused by Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

How can I get to_json to pass on data?

Comment: Seems like `data` doesn't have a proper encoding (`ASCII-8BIT` is used for binary data). What character does `\xE2` represent?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, it is a string with ASCII-8BIT characters that I am trying convert to JSON. \xE2 is just a random ASCII-8BIT character. But the actual strings that I am working with has more than 100 such characters.

Comment: ASCII only defines characters between codepoints 0 and 127. `\xE2` is codepoint 226 which isn't a valid ASCII character (hence the conversion error). I've asked what character it represents so we can figure out the string's actual encoding.

Comment: @Stefan  The original string is too long, but it has "card\xE2\x80\x99s" in which \xE2\x80\x99 stands for RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK as I found in the table here https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal

Comment: `data.force_encoding('utf-8')` should to the trick – it tells Ruby that the string is actually UTF-8. You should update your question with the actual data from the original string because `\xE2` on its own isn't a valid codepoint in UTF-8 and can't be converted.

Comment: @stefan, thanks! have updated question. Could you provide the answer so I can select your answer?

Comment: @Stefan please add your answer it has saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

`data.force_encoding('utf-8')`